# Dictionary: upset-like usage [compact syntax]

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I would like to do something similar using some short syntax:

```
var p = new Dictionary<string, string>();
p["a"] = "2";
p["a"] = "3";
```

instead I have to do:

```
if (p.ContainsKey("a"))
    p["a"] = "2";
else
    p.Add("a", "2");

if (p.ContainsKey("a"))
    p["a"] = "3";
else
    p.Add("a", "3");
```

Does it exist a compact syntax?

Comment: You can always create method to do it

Comment: You can do what you're trying to do... `p["a"] = "2";` is valid even if the key doesn't exist yet

Comment: @elmugrat: sorry, you are right. Can you answer instead of commenting? I will accept it. The problem was that I didn't inizialized the dictionary.

Comment: Also: you do realize that `p.Add("3")` is incorrect, right?

Comment: @Sam just accept the answer from Rudis, it's the same  :)

Comment: That's a *property bag", it has [been covered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131180/property-bag-for-c-sharp-class)

Comment: @HansPassant are you sure?  Looks like he's just looking for help using a normal Dictionary...

Comment: Using a dictionary to implement a PropertyBag is normal.

Comment: True, but I meant with general syntax as opposed to a specific application.  I guess it doesn't matter though as long as he gets an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p["a"] = "2";
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!p.ContainsKey("a"))
    p.Add("a", "2");
else
    p["a"] = "2";
```

The first should be preffered in fact, because it is performed faster.

Answer (score 9):

By the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Item` property:

> If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.

So compact syntax exists

Answer (score 1):

I have this extension method:

```
public static void AddOrKeep<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, V val)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, val);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
dict.AddOrKeep("a", "2");
```

It keeps the current value if existent, but adds it if new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method of Dictionary to check whether particular Key contains by dictionary or not.

E.g.

```
if (!p.ContainsKey("a"))
{
p.Add("a","2");
}
else
{
p["a"] = "2";
}
```